# Mobius strip and homeomorphism of a circle

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, quotient-spaces, mobius-band

I'm assigned a homework problem as follows:

Let $X$ be the Möbius strip, obtained as a quotient space of $[0,1] \times [0,1]$ (with subspace topology of $\mathbb{R}^2$) by identifying the pairs of points $(0,1) \sim (1, 1-y)$ for $0\leq y \leq 1$. Let $p: [0,1] \times [0,1] \rightarrow X$ be the associated quotient map. Let $A=\{(x,y) \in [0,1]\times[0,1] \mid y=0\text{ or }y=1 \}$. Show that $p(A)$ is homeomorphic to a circle.

I'm not sure where to start and can't seem to find an answer for the problem on this community. Please help. Thank you!

Comment: Have you tried to give an explicit homemorphism $h:p(A)\to S^1$?

Comment: I have not, unfortunately :(

Comment: Have you drawn a picture of the square, the identification, and the set of points in question? If not, that should help.

Comment: Thanks. That helps a bit :)